# Using Comparable interface to sort JAVA

Tags: java, comparable

Hi so for example i have :

```
string1[0] ="Banana";
string1[1] ="Apple";
string1[2] ="Pineapple";
string1[3] ="Mandarin";
```

I want to sort this alphabetically using comparable and `compareTo()` method.
So the result would be:

```
String1[0]="Apple";
String1[1]="Banana";
String1[2]="Mandarin";
String1[3]="Pineapple";
```

Could you just show me the skeleton of the code to do it plz ?

And is there a better way to sort it ?

Comment: Please try out first .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selection Sorting String Arrays (Java)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506471/selection-sorting-string-arrays-java)

Comment: Do you know where to use compareTo()?

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`Arrays.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29):

```
Arrays.sort(string1);
```

This will reorder the strings [lexicographically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Arrays.sort(string1);`

[see here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)